# PHP mail out late or when Apache server rebooted

Tags: apache, php

I used to have php mail out right away, now however it might be changes in php code on page, or fact that i changed servers. Mail out like 10 minutes after user register, but if i go and restart apache it goes trough right after apache restart.

What settings should i tweak for php or apache to make it send right away again.

P.S. this is random issue sometimes it sends right away!

```
            $from = "mail@otherdomain.com";
            $email_address = $ex[0][Email_Address];
            $ttc = "mymail@domain.com";
            $eol = "\r\n";

            $mime_boundary = md5(time());
            $headers .= "From:".$from .$eol;
            $headers .= "Reply-To:".$from.$eol;
            $headers .= "Return-Path:".$from.$eol;
            $headers .= "Bcc:".$ttc.$eol;
            $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$eol; 
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol;

            if (preg_match("/gmail/",$to))
            $headers = str_replace("\r\n","\n",$headers);

            $result=mail($email_address,$subject,$mess,$headers);
            header("location:home.html");
```

Comment: How are you sending mail? What do your log files show?

Comment: nothing unusial mail is sent with @mail(vars...); i added detail to main post

Comment: And what's in `$result`? Does PHP provide any mechanism to get errors from the return value from `mail()`?